# Does GHC use graph reduction?

Tags: graph-algorithms, reductions, compilers, haskell

I have read somewhere that GHC does not use graph reduction for compiling/evaluating expressions. Is this right? If yes, what does it use as an alternative?

Comment: I don't know how GHC works today, but a couple of years ago it
worked something like this: (1) The compiler desugars Haskell into a
small language called Core which is an extension of System Fω called
FC with pattern matching, let and coercions.  (2) Core is
compiled into STG code, which stands for Spineless-Tagless G-machine
and is a refinement of the older G-machine (short for Graph-Reduction
Machine, and for the lazy evaluation of functional programs in
supercombinator form).  (3) STG is compiled into C--.  (4) C-- can be
piped into any of the following:

Comment: (i) into direct machine code
generation, (ii) into C for feeding to gcc, (iii) into LLVM's
intermediate representation.

Comment: Here is a 2012 document: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/aos.pdf